# EM-wave equation in conductors with source terms

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations, conductors

The traditional modified Maxwell's equations to express em wave inside conductors that I have come across are:

$$
\nabla\cdot\mathbf E = 0 
\\\nabla\cdot\mathbf B = 0 
\\\nabla\times\mathbf E = -\frac{d\mathbf B}{dt}
\\\nabla\times\mathbf B = \mu\sigma\mathbf E+\mu\epsilon\frac{\partial\mathbf E}{\partial t}$$

where use of $\mathbf J=\sigma \mathbf E$ has been made

This makes sense, inside a conductor wherever there is an electric field, there is a corresponding current density due to free charge throughout

However I am not sure of the physical significance of setting the divergence of $\mathbf E$ to be zero?

Why is this done, and for that matter in the general wave equation in free space why does this also occur? As an EM wave needs to be generated by a source (the free space wave equation I'm guessing is to show the field itself behaves like a wave in general).

But for inside conductors, what would adding that the $\nabla\cdot\mathbf E = \rho/\epsilon$ actually physically mean, and what is the difference between the two?

I have had a good go at solving for the potentials $\phi$ and $\mathbf A$ with source terms.

Solving for $\mathbf A$ is pretty straightforward, providing the gauge choice is

$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf A - \mu\sigma\phi - \mu\epsilon\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = 0 $$

and the equation for the magnetic vector potential I get is:

$$
 - \nabla^2\mathbf A+\mu\sigma\frac{d\mathbf A}{dt} + \mu\epsilon\frac{d^2\mathbf A}{dt^2}=0
$$
(correct me if I'm wrong)

The standard potential formulation equation for $\phi$ is initially unchanged, however adding the gauge condition mentioned earlier you get a relatively complicated equation.

Another idea to use (most likely useless):

However is it valid to substitute $\rho/\epsilon$ for $\frac{\sigma\mathbf E}{\epsilon\mathbf v}$ where $\mathbf v$ is the velocity field, then exchange $\mathbf E$ for the potentials $\mathbf A$ and $\phi$, (as obviously $\mathbf J = \rho\mathbf v = \sigma\mathbf E$)?

Edit: doesnt setting p to be zero contradict the statement that $$ J = \sigma E $$ as $$ J = \rho * V $$ so must conclude that  E =0

Comment: Please use MathJax to format equations and symbols.

Comment: How? can i do that :/

Comment: Have a look here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You can't divide by a vector field

Comment: Correction then: Charge density = conductivity * abs(E/B)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the result you're looking for, but if you take the divergence of Ohm's law
$$
\nabla·\vec{J}=\sigma\nabla·\vec{E} \to \nabla·\vec{J}=\frac{\sigma\rho}{\epsilon_0}
$$
Now using the continuity equation
$$
\nabla·\vec{J}=-\frac{d\rho}{dt}
$$
And if we combine both results
$$
\frac{\sigma\rho}{\epsilon_0}=-\frac{d\rho}{dt} \to \rho=\rho_0e^{-\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}t}
$$
What we conclude from this is that, when the wave creates the current in the conductor, some charge distribution will appear as a consequence, but it will decrease exponentially, decaying faster if we're dealing with a good conductor where $\sigma\to\infty$. So assuming a rapid decay of the charge, we can consider that after some relatively short time $\tau$ we'll have $\rho=0$ and hence $\nabla·\vec{E}=0$ , as first stated. You can always wait until this result is valid.

Comment: Thanks for your input , and yes this is helpful as a way of understanding why some people would simplify the problem. However now i have 2 issues, how does this now come into play: the fact that when a conductor  has an e field inside, all of the charge is now on the surface. but the equation you have just derived seemingly contradicts this?

Comment: my guess( if you can shed some insight on this) is because these equations do not possess a boundary condition that the charge is not free to move infinitely and this equation shows the dispersal of charge if it were an infinite universe  of conductor ( much like charge disperses to the surface of a finite conductor . my second thing now to pick at is that the standard wave equation also DECAYS exponentially so shouldnt it also still make a difference if charge density decays exponentially, also if there is a current density there must be atleast some charge density no??

Comment: so in the case of normal E fields inside NON charged conductors how can there be a current density if it has zero charge density ( unless a very complex distribution whose integral is zero). Also one last thing... by setting the divergence of E to be zero... does that mean you are excluding the effects of the charges E fields themselfs

Comment: Okay, I am not 100% sure about the things I'm going to say, take that in mind. First, the result I derived shouldn't contradict the fact that in conductors have some superficial charge density, since it's only saying that rho (volume density) is zero. That means indeed that charges cannot occupy a certain volume, but it does not impose any restriction on the surface.

Comment: Yeah on second thought. i dont think this is done because it is uncharged. as if you supposedly wait for p to be zero. then the assumption of ohms law itself is UNTRUE as how can there be a current density without charge density?

Comment: As far as I understand, the way EM waves decays in the conductor is spatially, the deeper it gets, the more it decays, but there shouldn't be any problem with time (you can have a wave oscillating against some material for indefinite time, as long as you have a source for the waves). Also you can have current distribution while having rho equal to zero, for example by having negative particles flowing in one way and equally charged but positive particles flowing in the opposite direction as a consequence of a field. (net charge is zero). I don't quite get your last question about E divergence

Comment: Yes i understand that a non charged sphere can have a current density. however this only means that the volume integral of rho is zero. not that rho is zero. if rho is zero then that means that regardless of the combimation of pos/neg charges at all points in space there is zero charge ( ik this is used as a simplification instead of having a complicated density function). and my last question directly preceeds this, as of what i have previously stated is correct and if the charge DENSITY at a point is non zero, but the div of e is zero ( but it should be rho) then by setting div e = 0  -

Comment: regardless of Rho  means that your just ignoring div e basically

Comment: Now that ive honed in on what specifically im unsure about im going to make.a new.post asking a more direct.question