# Charge density of an uncharged sphere

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge, conductors

This post follows directly from my question about EM waves in conductors [EM-wave equation in conductors with source terms](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/621528/)

A more specific question in light of this.

Given an uncharged conductor:

We know $2$ things that are true:

$$ \vec J = \sigma\vec E $$

$$ \int \rho dV = 0 $$

In a conductor,

Maxwells equation:

$$ \vec\nabla\vec E = \rho / \epsilon_0 $$

is now set to $ \vec \nabla\vec E = 0 $

this implies $ \rho = 0 $

But, if $ \vec J = \sigma \vec E $

and  $ \vec J = \rho \vec v $

which means we have  no Current density inside the conductor

However using these equations for a EM wave inside a conductor, the amplitude DECAYS exponentially DUE TO current density ( energy conservation)

so my final question is: if $ \rho = 0 $ how is there a current density to effect an EM wave inside the conductor?

Answer (score 0):

First of all an **uncharged** conductor implies $\rho=0$, which implies $\vec\nabla\vec E=\rho/\epsilon_0=0$. Not the other way around. Having a **net**-charge of $0$, or $\int_V\rho dV=0$ still allows charge separation due to electric and magnetic fields provocated in the conductor, which is nothing but current (charge flow).

Now there are still cases where the net charge $\int_V\rho dV$ is $0$ but $\rho\neq 0$. The thing is that in reality there is no such case. Or more specifically, the only cases where you have a volume without charges at all would be a vacuum and even so if there is a photon passing thrue it could split into electron and positron creating a charge distribution.

So specially when talking about a conductor, that consists of metal for example, there will be neutral atoms, which naturally have a charge distribution within them. When we write $\rho=0$, we mean there is no big amount of charged ions or electron accumulation in a specific place. There are only neutral atoms, of which the electrons (in the case of a conductor) can freely move and are thus able to create a current density.

Comment: We are in agreement on your second statement. I understand why if the Integral of rho dv = 0 then there can still be a current density.   But... if rho is zero EVERYWHERE how can there be a current density? as every paper on EM waves set charge density to be zero yet still have a current density. A conductor that is half negative and half positive on either sides  in my mind , is still an uncharged conductor. as its integral is zero -

Comment: in the real world its best decribed as a density function that  is e.g positive then neg then pos then neg etc etc... the only way that you can TRULY say that Rho = 0 is if there is no positive or negative charge in that region at all....

Comment: i get that people say its zero as 0/volume = 0 so on AVG its zero. but when doing calculations about.current density. this APPROXIMATION is just clearly false...

Comment: @jensenpaull I will extend my answer then.

Comment: to your answer, i get thats what we mean. but what we mean is inherently different to what the math tells you , if it simply isnt true. then solving the field equations will lead to different results to reality and thus pointless. I still dont get how if p is zero and j depends on p being there then how in the case of  em waves in conductors u set p to zero.  as if p is zero the math simply isnt telling what really happens. when there is J in e.g wires then there must ALWAYS he an associated charge density else the quantity doesnt make sense.so -

Comment: so the e assumption that p is zero for em waves inductors is wrong..... so solving the field.equations for those wouldnt actually tell you what would really happen. much like the free space wave equation. the solution to the wave equation for that is also not an accurate picture of what would happen in reality. it is only when u add the source terms and solve that ,would get realistic solutions. 
so by substituting  ohms law into maxwells equations which defines a quantity that is p dependant -

Comment: and p is zero, then their cannot be a current density. so im assuming the assumption that all of the papers that i have read are simply saying this: These equations solve maxwells equations acknowledging that there IS a current  and a charge density p. but the charges themselfs dont have fields of their own so therefore saying that (div e =/ p/epsilon. )as p is non zero ( as this would come from a direct consequence of  substituting ohms law into the equation which does by DEFINITION define a non zero p function in the medium and thus artificially removing the fields of the charges themselfs

Comment: @jensenpaull I'm not sure I understood everything. But what you are saying is simply that the fact that $\rho= 0$ and $\vec J\neq 0$ are used in the same situation is bothering you because they are not compatible. I would propose then that you add a link to those papers to your answer, so that people can see exactly what you mean. If I missed anything please be a bit more specific with everything and try to use $\rho$ instead of p and $\vec E$ instead of e.